# Is there a "generate-migrations-db" equivalent in Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is the legacy documentation explaining what "generate-migrations-db" does:

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/07-Migrations

It says

> Generate migration classes from existing database connections
>   (doctrine-generate-migrations-db, doctrine-gen-migrations-from-db)

Also:

> **Generating Migrations**
>
> Doctrine offers the ability to generate sets of
>   migration classes for existing databases or existing models as well as
>   generating blank migration classes for you to fill in with the code to
>   make your schema changes.
>
> **From Database**
>
> If you have an existing database you can build **a set of migration
>   classes that will re-create** your database by running the following
>   command.
>
> `$ ./symfony doctrine:generate-migrations-db`

In other words: it takes the schema from the database and generates a migration that performs that schema creation. No entities, no classes, no mappings are used in this process. It just takes a DB and builds a migration class.

We do not have `generate-migrations-db` anymore. Do we have something that performs that task? I couldn't find. If it was replaced by some other command, please let me know. If it was just removed, please let know.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not aware of a command in Doctrine or the Migrations Bundle that creates migration files for an existing database.

So here's how I did it instead:

1. Install DoctrineMigrationsBundle
2. Create a new blank database
3. Update your config or parameters to point to this blank database rather than to your "real" one
4. Run `php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff`.  This will create a migrations file that creates your database tables etc from scratch
5. Change back your config/parameters

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Interesting. I can't test it right now, but I'll check later.

Comment: Did this also. Its kinda crude but it gets the job done and is way simpler than any other method I could find.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html), which can generate migration classes with sql statements for migration.

Comment: I had already read this entire documentation page. Which command does now what "generate-migrations-db" did? (i.e, create a migration based on the current database schema, not entities/classes)

Comment: `php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff` which generates a migrations class, with the differences between current database schema and the mappings of the entities.

Comment: Yes, right. But this is not what I want. I want the "generate-migrations-db" functionality. Read: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/07-Migrations#chapter_07_generating_migrations  "If you have an existing database you can build a set of migration classes that will re-create your database by running the following command." - it DOES NOT rely on the mappings of the entities, as I've said.